# Spring boot rest api Url not mapping with sucees console

Tags: spring-boot

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.5.RELEASE)
28-Sep-2018 10:30:58.561 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] 28-Sep-2018 10:30:59.108 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] 
28-Sep-2018 10:31:06.998 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration.openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
28-Sep-2018 10:31:07.155 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
28-Sep-2018 10:31:07.155 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
28-Sep-2018 10:31:07.248 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
28-Sep-2018 10:31:07.264 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
28-Sep-2018 10:31:07.311 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.initExceptionHandlerAdviceCache Detected @ExceptionHandler methods in repositoryRestExceptionHandler
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.155 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.initControllerAdviceCache Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@568ea9ef: startup date [Fri Sep 28 10:30:54 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.201 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.headCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.201 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.201 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[POST],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.postCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,java.lang.String) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.201 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[DELETE],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.deleteItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.ETag) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.217 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.optionsForCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.217 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getCollectionResourceCompact(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.217 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[PATCH],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.patchItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.ETag,java.lang.String) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.217 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.headForItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.217 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.optionsForItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.217 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.Resource<?>> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.233 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[PUT],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<? extends org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.putItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.ETag,java.lang.String) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.248 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws java.lang.Exception
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.264 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}/{propertyId}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws java.lang.Exception
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.264 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[DELETE],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<? extends org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.deletePropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.264 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReferenceCompact(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws java.lang.Exception
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.280 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[PATCH || PUT || POST],consumes=[application/json || application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<? extends org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.createPropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.http.HttpMethod,org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<java.lang.Object>,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.280 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}/{propertyId}],methods=[DELETE],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.deletePropertyReferenceId(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.295 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/{repository}/search],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.optionsForSearches(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.295 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearchCompact(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders,org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler)
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.295 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.headForSearch(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.lang.String)
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.295 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearch(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders)
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.295 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.optionsForSearch(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.lang.String)
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.295 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/{repository}/search],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchesResource org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.listSearches(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.295 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/{repository}/search],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.headForSearches(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.326 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/ || ],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController.optionsForRepositories()
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.326 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/ || ],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController.headForRepositories()
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.326 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/ || ],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryLinksResource> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController.listRepositories()
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.342 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/profile],methods=[GET]}" onto org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ProfileController.listAllFormsOfMetadata()
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.342 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/profile],methods=[OPTIONS]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ProfileController.profileOptions()
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.358 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/profile/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/schema+json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.JsonSchema> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySchemaController.schema(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.358 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/profile/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/alps+json || */*]}" onto org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.alps.AlpsController.descriptor(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.358 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/profile/{repository}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/alps+json]}" onto org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.alps.AlpsController.alpsOptions()
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.811 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.afterSingletonsInstantiated Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.811 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.autodetect Bean with name 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.842 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanInstance Located MBean 'dataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource]
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.889 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger.logStarted Started SpringBootApp in 16.437 seconds (JVM running for 32.367)
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.920 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.936 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/ng-ols-platformservices] startup failed due to previous errors
28-Sep-2018 10:31:08.998 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@568ea9ef: startup date [Fri Sep 28 10:30:54 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
28-Sep-2018 10:31:09.014 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.destroy Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
28-Sep-2018 10:31:09.014 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanRegistrationSupport.unregisterBeans Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
28-Sep-2018 10:31:09.014 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.destroy Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-09-28 10:31:09.014  INFO 23088 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2018-09-28 10:31:09.030  INFO 23088 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
28-Sep-2018 10:31:09.045 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [ng-ols-platformservices] registered the JDBC driver [org.h2.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
28-Sep-2018 10:31:09.076 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [D:\appache\apache-tomcat-8.5.34-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.34\webapps\ng-ols-platformservices.war] has finished in [29,781] ms
28-Sep-2018 10:31:09.076 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [D:\appache\apache-tomcat-8.5.34-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.34\webapps\docs]
28-Sep-2018 10:31:09.186 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
28-Sep-2018 10:31:09.248 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [D:\appache\apache-tomcat-8.5.34-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.34\webapps\docs] has finished in [172] ms
28-Sep-2018 10:31:09.248 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [D:\appache\apache-tomcat-8.5.34-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.34\webapps\examples]
28-Sep-2018 10:31:10.920 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
28-Sep-2018 10:31:11.045 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [D:\appache\apache-tomcat-8.5.34-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.34\webapps\examples] has finished in [1,797] ms
28-Sep-2018 10:31:11.061 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [D:\appache\apache-tomcat-8.5.34-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.34\webapps\host-manager]
28-Sep-2018 10:31:11.186 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [D:\appache\apache-tomcat-8.5.34-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.34\webapps\host-manager] has finished in [125] ms
28-Sep-2018 10:31:11.186 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [D:\appache\apache-tomcat-8.5.34-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.34\webapps\manager]
28-Sep-2018 10:31:11.248 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [D:\appache\apache-tomcat-8.5.34-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.34\webapps\manager] has finished in [62] ms
28-Sep-2018 10:31:11.248 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [D:\appache\apache-tomcat-8.5.34-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.34\webapps\ROOT]
28-Sep-2018 10:31:11.295 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
28-Sep-2018 10:31:11.311 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [D:\appache\apache-tomcat-8.5.34-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.34\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [63] ms
28-Sep-2018 10:31:11.326 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
28-Sep-2018 10:31:11.358 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
28-Sep-2018 10:31:11.373 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 32167 ms
```

i deployed war to apache tomcat webapps folder and I started apache tomcat services I got below console log ,
after my rest api url :igiven like localhost:8080/api/user-profile

My @RequestMapping("/api")
 @PostMapping("/user-profiles")

but am getting 404 error .please help to resolve this ,I am stuck with 2 days about the url mapping issue

```
package com.ce.resources;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.ce.dto.UserProfileDTO;
import com.ce.services.UserProfileService;
import com.ce.web.rest.util.HeaderUtil;
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserprofileResource {
    private final UserProfileService userProfileService;
    public UserprofileResource(UserProfileService userProfileService ) {
        this.userProfileService=userProfileService;
    }

    //create user profile
     @PostMapping("/user-profiles")
    public ResponseEntity<UserProfileDTO> createUserProfile(@Valid @RequestBody UserProfileDTO userProfileDTO) throws URISyntaxException {
                UserProfileDTO userProfileDto=userProfileService.userProfileSave(userProfileDTO);
                UserProfileDTO result = userProfileService.userProfileSave(userProfileDto);

        return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/user-profiles/" + result.getId()))
                .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert("userProfile", result.getId().toString()))
                .body(result);

    }

}
```

Comment: What package is your RestController in and what package is the main spring boot application? If the RestController is not in the same package tree as the application it will not be picked up by the component scan driven from the SpringBootApplication annotation.

Comment: My package com.ce.resource >> UserProfileResource.java and SpringBootApp.java


same package I have main SpringBootApp.java
 and UserProfileResource classes

Comment: Add your rest API class please.

Comment: Added please check above

Comment: @jack what is war file name that you deployed on tomcat try to use `localhost:8080/warname/api/user-profile`

Comment: not working above url

Comment: what is war file name, and check the answer of David

Comment: ng-ols-platformservices

Answer (score 1):

Your correct URL depends on the way you deploy your war file on Tomcat.

First, you deploy application on the folder webapps/ROOT. The url should be like what you want, localhost:8080/api/user-profiles. You can rename your war file to ROOT.war and copy into the folder webapps.

Second, you deploy application like a subfolder in the folder webapps. The url should be like this localhost:8080/subfolder-name/api/user-profiles. Simply you copy war file to the folder webapps so that your url is localhost:8080/war-file-name/api/user-profiles.

@jack if your war is ng-ols-platformservices.war so your url is localhost:8080/ng-ols-platformservices/api/user-profiles

Comment: http://localhost:8080/ng-ols-platformservices/api/user-profiles

>>I tried seems same problem 404 error

Comment: This api consumes method POST, you should test it with a restclient tool like postman and enter body data.

Comment: Yes ,I am using postman but still getting 404 ,I don't know what is cause of this problem

Comment: You're getting 404 after submitting postman with that url, is it right? If yes error 404 said that you are calling a url that doesn't exist. Look back your code, after saving object userProfileDto you just call an other api (/api/user-profiles/" + result.getId()) at the end of method createUserProfile. Unfortunately you have'nt created it yet. It's  root cause i think.